# Validation of JSON Object With @Valid and @Requestbody in SpringBoot

Tags: json, spring-boot, rest

I am trying to validate a JSON body within a post method. Here is a sample code:

```java
@PostMapping(value = "GetInfo")
public ResponseEntity<Person> getOffers(@Valid @RequestBody InfoRequest infoRequest) {
   //generate person response according to inforequest JSON.
   Person person = PersonGenerator.getOffers(infoRequest);
   return new ResponseEntity<>(person, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

When I send JSON body to get info (for ex: `Name` and `Age`) I want the program to throw an error if some extra fields are entered that are not needed for the `Person` class. As an example in below `ExtraField`. But `@RequestBody` and `@Valid` annotations are just checking for fields that have a match. Since it is filtered (afaik in this case `ExtraField` is filtered) I can't get full JSON to analyze `infoRequest` to find if any extra information was sent.

```json
{
    "Name": "sample",
    "Age": "sample",
    "ExtraField": "prevent",
}
```

I know there are some libraries to check JSON files. But first I have to know what is coming :).
If there is no annotation to see extra fields entered. How can I extract and analyze JSON file*

Note: Changing parameter type `infoRequest` as String is not an option for security purposes.

Comment: Are you using Jackson for JSON serialization/deserialization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the Spring Boot configuration will disables Jackson `DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES` feature. One possible solution could be enabling it again in you `application.yml` file as follows:

```
spring.jackson.deserialization.fail-on-unknown-properties=true
```

This will change the behaviour for Jackson `ObjectMapper` if you want finer-grained configuration you might use `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = false)` as follows:

```java
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = false)
public class InfoRequest {
    (...)
}
```